# Basic polymorphism in Java/casting a superclass as a subclass

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism, subclass

I'm working through a Java polymorphism exercise and struggling to understand type conversion & how to call subclass-specific methods. I have a class Dog:

```
public class Dog
{
    private final String breed;

    public Dog(String b)
    {
        breed = b;
    }

    //More Dog methods (bark, eat, etc.)
}
```

as well as a subclass SledDog, who can  pull a sled:

```
public class SledDog extends Dog
{
    public SledDog(String b)
    {
        super(b);
    }

    public void pullSled()
    {
        System.out.println("pulling the sled");
    }
}
```

In my application, I declare 3 dogs - two regular Dogs and one SledDog. I pass them into an array of Dogs, and I loop through that array. If the dog is a sled dog, I want him to pullSled() - but I can't figure out how to call the method, since it belongs to a subclass. My instructions tell me to cast the array item into a SledDog object, but I can't figure out how, or why it is necessary. I thought that since the object passed to array is already a SledDog, it should have access to pullSled(). Here's my attempt.

```
public class DogApp
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Dog firstDog = new Dog("Greyhound");
        Dog secondDog = new Dog("Terrier");
        SledDog sledDog = new SledDog("Husky");

        Dog[] dogArray = new Dog[]{firstDog, secondDog, sledDog};

        for(Dog d : dogArray)
        {
            //Makes sense, only want to pullSled() if d is a SledDog
            if(d instanceof SledDog)
            {               
                // This is the part I'm confused about
                d = (SledDog) d;
                d.pullSled();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are pretty close, just cast it and call the method:

```
((SledDog)d).pullSled();
```

inside the `if (d instance of SledDog)` condition.

Also, I can't see the declaration of `dogArray`. Be sure you have declared and initialized it correctly.

Comment: So while this *works* ... it's a bad design. Defining `Dog` as an abstract class with an abstract `pullSled()` then overriding `pullSled()` in the concrete subclasses is generally the preferred way to go about it. At the very least define a `pullSlead()` in `Dog` then override it in the subclasses.

Comment: This worked! Regarding dogArray - looks like the declaration didn't make it into my example above, I have edited it to include it.

Answer (score 2):

When talking about OOP, trying to discern what the concrete subclass actually is generally means you're doing something wrong.

You could approach this issue by defining a default `pullSled()` in your `Dog` class, then overriding it:

```
public class Dog
{
    private final String breed;

    public Dog(String b)
    {
        breed = b;
    }

    public boolean pullSled()
    {
        System.out.println("Dude, I'm a " + breed + ", not a Siberian Husky!");
        return false;
    }

    //More Dog methods (bark, eat, etc.)
}

public class SledDog extends Dog
{
    public SledDog(String b)
    {
        super(b);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean pullSled()
    {
        System.out.println("pulling the sled");
        return true;
    }
}
```

Another option over this simple example, you could also define a field and `boolean canPullSled()`:

```
public class Dog
{
    private final String breed;
    protected boolean canPullSled; 

    public Dog(String b)
    {
        breed = b;
    }

    public boolean canPullSled()
    {
        return canPullSled;
    }

    public boolean pullSled()
    {
       if (canPullSled)
       {
           System.out.println("pulling the sled");
           return true;
       }
       else
       {
           System.out.println("Dude, I'm a " + breed + ", not a Siberian Husky!");
           return false;
       }
    }

    // other stuff
}

public class SledDog extends Dog
{
    public SledDog(String b)
    {
        super(b);
        this.canPullSled = true;
    }
}
```

Or use a Builder ... or a fluent interface ... or ...

In the end, `instanceof` is really a last resort, used only when nothing else will do.

Answer (score 2):

**There is difference between an object and a reference to an object.**

All SledDogs are Dogs but all Dogs are not SledDogs. So according to this logic (as far as compiler understands), following code is fine.

```
Dog myDog = new SledDog(); // This compiles
```

while

```
SledDog myDog = new Dog(); // Error
```

does not work.

---

So in the first line, the tricky part is that you have an object of `SledDog` class but you are referring to it by a reference of `Dog` class. (Since all SledDogs are Dogs, this is perfectly fine)

But while doing this, you are ignoring it's `SledDog`ness. You will be able to access features of SledDog that are inherited from `Dog`, but SledDog specific features will be unavailable. Remember that object is still a SledDog but you are **acknowledging** it as a mere `Dog`.

So in order to access them, you'll have to refer it using a reference of `SledDog` class. ---> **Hence the typecast is required**.

```
SledDog typeCastedMyDog = (SledDog) myDog;
```

Now you can access the pullSled() method.

---

The same logic applies when you put all of them in an array of Dogs.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a  real polymorhic case you can use

```
superclassName referenceName=subclassObject
```

in this way you can access all methods of subclass by use of superclass reference.

Just a hint  to get you started,try and take it further
good luck!